# Bootstrap Carousel won't initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I hate that this is my first question, but I have looked all over and tried to find why my code is not working. Only the first slide loads, and when you click either the left or right arrow, it acts like it is a "link" to take you to that position on the page. Here is what I have so far that is relevant to this (you can view it on www.KatyEnglish.com). Any/all help will be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks!

```
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/textillate-master/assets/animate.css">
</head>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/slider6.jpg" alt="Katy English Photography Portraits">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
            <img src="img/slider1.jpg" alt="Katy English Photography Portraits">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
            <img src="img/slider5.jpg" alt="Katy English Photography Portraits">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
            <img src="img/slider3.jpg" alt="Katy English Photography Portraits">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
            <img src="img/slider2.jpg" alt="Katy English Photography Portraits">
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
    </div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/textillate-master/jquery.textillate.js"></script>
<script src="js/textillate-master/assets/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script src="js/textillate-master/assets/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('.tlt').textillate({
      in: {effect:'rollIn'}
    });
  })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just press F12 on your browser. You will find it.

Comment: One issue I see is that you are including jQuery twice, you should only include it once. What errors(if any) are you getting in your developer console?

Comment: Also in carousel docs is said: The data-ride="carousel" attribute is used to mark a carousel as animating starting at page load. It cannot be used in combination with (redundant and unnecessary) explicit JavaScript initialization of the same carousel. So try to comment your explicit js init of the carousel.

Comment: The path to your Bootstrap .js is incorrect.  Everything else looks fine, but your webpage can't access the scripts to power the carousel.  I believe this is what @Bikal Bhattarai was trying to point out.  Make sure you're using developer tools and tracking your errors.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. I am pretty new to web development, and forget to use f12. After checking, you are all right that I was calling Javascript twice, and that my bootstrap js file was not in the right path. I corrected the filepath name, and now it works. Thank you all!!!!!!